# The expectation of $\log(X)\cdot \mathbb{I}\{X\le a\}$, where $X$ follows gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

Given a random variable $X\sim {\text Gamma} (\alpha ,\beta )$, and define $Y=\ln(X)\cdot \mathbb{I}\{X\le a\}$, does it exist a closed-form expression for $\mathbb{E}\{Y\}$ or an approximated one?

In detail,
$$\mathbb{E}\{Y\}=\int_0^a\ln(X)\,dF_X(x)$$
where $F_X(x)=\frac {\gamma (\alpha ,\beta x)}{\Gamma (\alpha )}$.

If we know the CDF of $Y$, we can solve it using a similar method in [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/gam-logmean.html).